# Submitting sitemap.xml to Google via php

Tags: seo, sitemap, google-search-console

On the sitemaps.org it says that it is possible to submit the sitemap.xml via HTTP request to the search engine. However I'm unable to find documentation on how to do this for Google. I'm only finding the documentation on submitting it via Google Webmaster Tools.

Any ideas, is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ping the sitemap url :

> http://www.google.com/webmasters/sitemaps/ping?sitemap=URLOFSITEMAP.xml

[Pinging google sitemap after every new article submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332601/pinging-google-sitemap-after-every-new-article-submission)

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to submit and resubmit `sitemap.xml` to search engines. You can define them in your `robots.txt` file and web crawlers will find them and crawl them frequently.

Comment: I guess this would be the difference of being good at what you do, and expecting good things to come from what you do. You should submit your sitemap every 24 hours. Google even recommends hourly at minimum if your website is continuously changing with new content (ie forums etc)