# How to generate sitemap.xml and submit to search engines

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc, dynamic

I am developing a dynamic blog website using spring MVC . recently I heard about sitemap which helps search engines to crawl through the websites having dynamic pages and improves SEO, my question is 
1)how can I generate such sitemap.xml file and submit it on search engines .
2)what if I add new article daily? so I need to again submit my sitemap to search engines.
I am newbie to SEO and all and really confused about this stuff . So please guide me how can I generate my sitemap.xml file and submit it to search engine as soon as I add new article in my database.

Comment: You said you are new to SEO, maybe this http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/seo-tutorial/  is a good start for you.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** I couldn't include all the links I wanted to because of lack of reputation, there's lots to Google in here.

Your assumption that an XML sitemap for SEO is beneficial is correct - it's a URL discovery method for search engines.

There's already an answer for generating the XML sitemaps with Spring MVC : [How to generate the correct sitemap namespace using JAXB and Spring @ResponseBody in controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402575/how-to-generate-the-correct-sitemap-namespace-using-jaxb-and-spring-responsebod)

When generating your XML sitemap, filter out any pages that **don't** pass the following conditions:

- Do not return a valid 200 response code
- Contains a meta level "noindex" or x-robots NOINDEX http header
- Contains a canonical reference to a different page, i.e. /example.html rel="canonical" href="page.html"

  - Page is blocked by robots.txt

The idea is to keep the XML sitemap as clean as possible; no redirects, no blocked URLs, etc...

Other important actions:

- When a new page is added to the site, add it into your sitemap and ping Google ([Pinging google sitemap after every new article submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332601/pinging-google-sitemap-after-every-new-article-submission))
- If your sitemaps exceed 50,000 urls, nest them in a sitemap index file
- List your sitemaps in robots.txt
- Submit sitemap to Google Search Console

Answer (score 0):

I use [Integrity Pro](http://peacockmedia.software/mac/integrity/) for custom web apps. There are a lot of free apps but this is the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to generate a sitemap is to use a sitemap generator. For example you can try [Slickplan](https://slickplan.com).

It has the site crawler, which you can use to import the structure of your website and create a sitemap from it. At the end you can export your sitemap in several file formats, and also thanks to a few integration modules import it directly to CMS: WordPress, Joomla!, cocnrete5, Drupal and ExpressionEngine.